# ruby net-ssh login shell

Tags: ruby, bash, ssh, net-ssh

Is there any way i can get a login shell in ruby using net-ssh?
Is that even possible?

By login shell i mean the ones the source /etc/profile..

Comment: It should definitely be possible but not sure how in the API. Maybe `open_channel`? It's hard to tell.

Comment: doesn't work i still don't get a login shell. Actually hoped this would work though..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Net-SSH is too low level to simply provide this up front (the way it is now, anyways). You can check out Net-SSH-Shell which builds upon Net-SSH to add login shell functionality: https://github.com/mitchellh/net-ssh-shell

The implementation is solid and works, however I found its not too useful since you can't specifically extract things like stderr or exit status because the commands run in a sub-shell, so you can only get stdout. The net-ssh-shell library uses some hacks to get the exit status.

I've needed a "login shell" for my own Ruby projects and to do this I've generally executed things directly into the shell using the following code:

```
def execute_in_shell!(commands, shell="bash")
  channel = session.open_channel do |ch|
    ch.exec("#{shell} -l") do |ch2, success|
      # Set the terminal type
      ch2.send_data "export TERM=vt100\n"

      # Output each command as if they were entered on the command line
      [commands].flatten.each do |command|
        ch2.send_data "#{command}\n"
      end

      # Remember to exit or we'll hang!
      ch2.send_data "exit\n"

      # Configure to listen to ch2 data so you can grab stdout
    end
  end

  # Wait for everything to complete
  channel.wait
end
```

With this solution you still don't get exit status or stderr of commands run into the login shell, but at least the commands are executed in that context.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good project, just a few years old, and there's a couple pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nicer way to do this now. Instead you can use a shell subsystem with a pty to get everything you would expect from a shell login:

```
Net::SSH.start(@config.host, @config.user, :port => @config.port, :keys => @config.key, :config => true) do |session|
  session.open_channel do |channel|
    channel.request_pty
    channel.send_channel_request "shell" do |ch, success|
      if success
        ch.send_data "env\n"
        ch.send_data "#{command}\n"
        ch.on_data do |c, data|
          puts data
        end
      end
      channel.send_data "exit\n"

      channel.on_close do
        puts "shell closed"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

end