# Running the workflows thru Ruby and Test gets passed but the workflows does not trigger

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

I am trying to run the informatica workflows thru ruby. Using the Net-ssh gem. When i run my test it gets passed but my jobs are not triggered when i check the logs they are not creating.

Below is my code.

```
Given(/^Run ESP jobs$/) do
  require 'net/ssh'
  Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => "my_password" ) do
    # I am trying to connect to remote server.
    ssh.exec('cd /etl/dev/scripts/bin')
    puts ssh.exec('pwd')
    # After changing the directory i tried to see my path but my path still 
    # shows in the home 
    # below command is in this path "/etl/dev/scripts/bin"
    ssh.exec('startworkflow01.ksh folder_name workflow_name')
  end
end
```

I expect to run the job. Please provide me your suggestions in completing this task. Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for your response, I did tried using exec!.
Given(/^Run ESP jobs$/) do
require 'net/ssh'
Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => "my_password" ) do |ssh|
ssh.exec!('cd /etl/dev/scripts/bin')
puts ssh.exec!('pwd')
ssh.exec!('startworkflow01.ksh folder_name workflow_name')
end
end
The test is getting passed but if i check the logs they are not generating any logs. When i run thru linux manually it works.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `exec` nor `exec!` will preserve state between calls, since those commands are not running on top of a shell like Bash or Zsh.

Therefore to run a script in a certain folder you either have to address the script with an absolute path:

```
ssh.exec!("/the/path/to/my_script")
```

Or string related commands together with `;` in the same `exec` call, to preserve state:

```
ssh.exec!("cd /the/path/to; my_script; ...")
```

If you want to run everything on top of a real shell, then it gets more complicated. I recommend to look here for more details on that:

[ruby net-ssh login shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051782/ruby-net-ssh-login-shell)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using the below code
    Given(/^Run informatica jobs$/) do
    require 'net/ssh'
    Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => "password" ) do |ssh|
    ssh.exec!( '/etl/dev/scripts/bin/startworkflow01.ksh app_CCMLB_FPERX 
    wf_4100_CCML_CAP_PKG_EXT')
    end
    end
Still i dont see any logs for it.

Comment: And does startworkflow01.ksh expect a particular working directory? Does it expect other shell variables to be present? Note that it is NOT a login shell, so no `.bashrc` files will be run to set up your environment.

Comment: I kind of able to change the dir. When i run the test, I am getting this bash: startworkflow01.ksh: command not found. startworkflow01.ksh is present in the path above mentioned. I am not sure what it means.

Comment: You should run it with `./startworkflow01.ksh`. Note the dot and slash. Like I said your environment will not be set up. If it does not work you would be better off using something like `Net::SSH::Shell` instead: https://github.com/mitchellh/net-ssh-shell